# Not able to enter the data with SendKeys Method in appium

Tags: android, automation, appium

I am trying to enter my email address in the field, but when I inspect the element I see a very big rectangle for the edit box. Though I am able to find that through class name. but when I try to enter the value through `SendKeys` method, My test gets passed, but I am not able to see the text entered in the field. Take a look at the screenshot of the mobile view. [Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC5DD.png)

PS: I am testing the flutter application. So does it make any difference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you share your MobileElement/XPath?

Comment: @kenneth Here is my code where I written the logic https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/31346217?key=6249e54d524c56ba89b217442997d42a and here is the xpath/element https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/31346216?key=7d89b7c53fe730e618990b858734cb95 Hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your definition for Email_input is by class name and not an xpath, so you don't need the forward slashes. It should be:

`private By Email_input = By.className("android.widget.EditText");`

Don't know what your Parent_Signin_pageObject class does but ultimately you would need something like this to enter the text:

```
driver.findElement(Email_input).sendKeys("user@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Hi @javageddon I have removed the double slashes from the text. It is still not working.

Comment: Parent_Signin_pageObject contains the method which returns the Element of the edit text and I am passing the value there. same thing you have mentioned here.